# How to center align a div vertically which uses bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row with content which should be in the center of the site and a footer at the bottom. The content are divided into two `6 column`. i want it to center align vertically according to the screen size. so i tried to give some percentage of `top` with a position `relative` but it doesn't work out.

If i give `margin-top` it is working. In order to make the top we have to give the position, so i have given it `relative` I don't want position `absolute` then the footer will come at the top of the site. Other content also will come top i thnik.

How to center align the contents and footer should stay at bottom all time all display size.

HTML

```
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-md-6 vertical'> content</div>
<div class='col-md-6 vertical'>content right</div>
</div>
<footer>sit at bottom</footer>
```

CSS

```
.vertical{
    position:relative;
   /* margin-top:20%; */ /*works*/
    top:20%; /*not works even providing position */
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FwmL4/1/) **NOTE: Don't forgot to resize the window then only you can able to see the two column division**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class='row'>
 <div class='col-md-6 '>
   <div class="vertical"> content</div>
 </div>
 <div class='col-md-6 '>
   <div class="vertical"> content</div>
 </div>
</div>
<footer>sit at bottom</footer>

.vertical{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  height: 200px /* Accordingly */
}
```

Working Fiddle [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FwmL4/1/).

Comment: It can but something must have height context. But i guess you should not do that. Can you tell me what is the purpose of using height in % ..?

Comment: if i didn't give height in % also it will work in a responsive way isn't it?

Comment: Yes it will work out in responsive. You don't have to worry about responsiveness in that case. Actually to keep it responsive you should not provide height in %. That may break it.

Comment: so to keep responsive when i use bootstrap i don't have to worry about giving anything in px. example i can give margin-top:250px without worry to any elements. isn't?

Comment: Thanks. One more doubt why `position:relative` not working here.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using `display: table-cell`, there is one more way to do it but is not so cross-browser at this moment. Take a look at [CSS3 Flexbox](http://learnlayout.com/flexbox.html).

Comment: Thanks +1. Do you know why position:relative doesn't work here?

Comment: There are too many styles involved in bootstrap, these things need time and there can be multiple ways to achieve the same result. Its just a matter of how cross-browser or how dynamic you need your layout to be.